# Best way to cite CVE (bibtex)

Tags: bibtex

My question is barely simple and due to the fact that I didn't found out any information about that on the web :

What is the best way to cite CVE ([site](http://www.cve.mitre.org/)) entries in latex with Bibtex? Are they any dictionaries referencing them all, as we can have for RFC ([site](http://www.ietf.org/rfc.html))?

Furthermore, are they any standards for such citations?

For example, if I may wish to cite the [CVE 2014-0160](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-0160) or any else, is there any librairy including it already -that I could cite-, or may I write them all by hand when I want to quote a CVE ?

Comment: You might use the "catch-all" `@misc` entry type.

Comment: @Mico Do you mind explaining a bit more what you mean please ?

Comment: The CVEs can have 4 to 7 digit identifiers. It would help if you provided a specific example of a CVE you wish to cite.

Comment: @Mico I updated my question, do not hesitate to ask me to clarify if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

In APA, the CVE list could be qualified as a database. For Example:

```
@MISC{CVE-2014-0160,
  title = {{CVE}-2014-0160.},
  howpublished = "Available from MITRE, {CVE-ID} {CVE}-2014-0160.",
  month=dec # "~3",
  year = {2013},
  url={http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2014-0160 },
  urldate={19 April 2015}
}
```